# Trim dots from email address

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

How do I trim any dots before `@mail.com`? I am doing jQuery email validation and need to get rid of all the dots from username.

```
                $('document').ready(function(){
             var email_state = false;
              $('#email').on('keyup', function(){
                var email = $('#email').val();
                if (email == '') {
                    email_state = false;
                    return;
                }
                $.ajax({
          url: 'index.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            'email_check' : 1,
            'email' : email,
          },
          success: function(response){.....
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt whatsoever to solve this yourself?

Comment: Yes i did, found something similar but don't know how to merge with my function

Comment: Now that you’ve added code, I see that this has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please use the proper tags.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex**: [`\.(?![^@]+$`)](https://regex101.com/r/ZfOYfl/1/)

One line code: `email.replace(/\.(?![^@]+$)/gy, '')`

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.clear()
  var s = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log(s.replace(/\.(?![^@]+$)/g, ''));
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:myFunction()">
  <input id="input" type="text" value="bla.bla.bla.@mail.net.com"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need it integrated in my code... don't know how to do it! Check my post. Thx

Comment: Tried like this: var email = $('#email').val();
  email = email.replace(/\.(?![^@]+$)/g, '');

Answer (score 2):

Use `.replace(/\./g, "")` for the part before `@`

```js
function removeDots(email){
  var email_s = email.split("@");
  return email_s[0].replace(/\./g, "")+"@"+email_s[1];
}

var email = "some.emai.l@mail.com";
console.log(removeDots(email));
```

In your code's context

```
function removeDots(email) {
  var email_s = email.split("@");
  return email_s[0].replace(/\./g, "") + "@" + email_s[1];
}

var email = "some.emai.l@mail.com";
console.log(removeDots(email));
$('document').ready(function() {
  var email_state = false;
  $('#email').on('keyup', function() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    email = removeDots(email); // call function here to remove dots
    if (email == '') {
      email_state = false;
      return;
    }
    // Rest of your code
  });
  // Rest of your code
});
```

Comment: Find my edited post, how do i integrate the function, sorry for being a total noob!

Comment: @Lugifah Its okay. see the answer.

Comment: "some.emai.l@mail.com";  ... should be replaced with $('#email'); ?

Answer (score 1):

First get the `username` of email using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) then remove all the `.` using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and `/\./g`. Below is an example:

```js
var email = "abc.d.e@mail.com";
var splitted = email.split("@");
console.log(splitted[0].replace(/\./g,"") + "@" + splitted[1]);
```

For updated question:

```
var email_state = false;
$('#email').on('keyup', function(){
  var email = $('#email').val();
  if (email == '') {
    email_state = false;
    var splitted = email.split("@");
    email = splitted[0].replace(/\./g,"") + "@" + splitted[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Find my edited post, how do i integrate the function, sorry for being a total noob!